# Assembly Version Checking in .Net

Tags: .net, assemblyversionattribute

I am trying to fully get my head around assembly versions and strong names in .NET

I found [This Assembly Versioning Article](http://philippetruche.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/net-assembly-versioning-lifecycle/) stating that only Major.Minor.Build is used in version matching.  I cannot find anything that can confirm/deny this.

> Assembly Version Format 
>   ...
>   Revision:
>   Assemblies with the same name,
>   major, and minor version numbers but different revisions are intended
>   to be fully interchangeable. This would be appropriate to fix a
>   security hole in a previously released assembly.

[MS Articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28VS.71%29.aspx) say things like:

> The assembly version number is part of an assembly's identity and plays a key part in binding to the assembly and in version policy... Version checking only occurs with strong-named assemblies.

Does this mean that say 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.1 are interchangeable in a strong name environment but 1.0.1.1 is not?

What is the definitive answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find anything in the linked article stating that only Major.Minor.Build is used in version matching.  In fact all four components of a version are used.

The key point is `intended to be interchangeable`.  Whether or not they *are* actually interchangeable depends on the author, who is free to respect or ignore the MS guidelines.

A vendor of a shared assembly that is installed in the GAC can supply a publisher policy file to redirect from old to new version of the assembly.  He should only do this if the new version is backward compatible with the old one.

Comment: Thanks.  I shouldn't have said "stated."  *I* should have stated that I did not know how to interpret what the quoted section influenced exactly.

Answer (score 3):

The assembly's `AssemblyVersion`-attribute is being evaluated completely when comparing versions. Meaning that changing one part of the version number will result non-matching assemblies.

One way to work around this is to let the `AssemblyVersion`-attribute always unchanged e.g set to `[AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.0")]`and use the `AssemblyFileVersion`-attribute for changing versions such as revisions, e.g. `[AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.20120909")]`. That gives you the possibility to update the version of a strongly named assembly without updating all references.

Comment: "One way to work around this is to let the AssemblyVersion-attribute always unchanged" - This is not always desirable.  For example, the assembly download cache will only be updated if the AssemblyVersion has changed.